# Traceback error when handling text files

Tags: python, file-handling, traceback

I have created this code, which performs a quiz and then writes the result to a text file based on a user input (class).
All the file handling code seems sound to me, but when I run the program, I experience a "Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):" error, and then the program crashes out.

I just had the same problem with a different bit of code and got an answer, but I have not made the error I made again (trying to write multiple variables to a file at once), so that answer isn't applicable this time.

```
import random 

forename="" 
surname=""
classno=0
numberone=0 
numbertwo=0
correct=False
score=0
ops = ["+", "x", "-"] 



while forename == "" or forename.isnumeric():
    forename=input("What is your first name? ")
    if forename == "": 
        print("You have to enter your first name.")
    if forename.isnumeric() == True:
        print("Your name must contain letters.")

while surname == "" or surname.isnumeric():
    surname=input("What is your surname? ")
    if surname == "":
        print("You have to enter your name.")
    if surname.isnumeric() == True:
        print("Your name must contain letters.")

while classno not in [1,2,3]: 
    while True:
        try:
            classno=int(input("What class are you in? "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("That wasn't right. Please try again.")



for x in range(10): 
    operation=random.choice(ops) 

if operation == "-": 
    numberone=random.randint(0,10) 
    numbertwo=random.randint(0,numberone)

elif operation == "x":
    numberone=random.randint(0,12)
    numbertwo=random.randint(0,12) 

else:
    numberone=random.randint(0,100)
    numbertwo=random.randint(0,(100-numberone))

while True:
        try:
            answer=int(input("What is " + str(numberone) + str(operation) + str(numbertwo) + "? "))
            break 
        except ValueError: 
            print("Incorrect input. Please try again.")


if operation=="+":
    if answer==numberone+numbertwo:
        correct=True

elif operation=="-":
    if answer==numberone-numbertwo:
        correct=True

else:
    if answer==numberone*numbertwo:
        correct=True

if correct==True:
    print("Correct!")
    score=score+1

else:
    print("Wrong!")

correct = False



info = str(forename) + "," + str(surname) + "," + str(score) + "\n"    



if classno == 1:
    file=open("class1.txt", "a")

elif classno == 2:
    file=open("class2.txt", "a")

else:
    file=open("class3.txt", "a")


maxnames = sum(1 for line in file)
name = [[] for i in range(maxnames)]   #creates empty list


for count in range(maxnames):
    line = file.readline()   #defines one line
    line=line.strip("\n")   #defines where lines end
    data = line.split(",")  #defines each data particle

    name[count].append(data[0])   #puts name in
    name[count].append(data[1])   #puts scores in
    name[count].append(data[2])
    name[count].append(data[3])


if forename == name[c][0] and surname == name[c][1]:
    name[c][4]=name[c][3]
    name[c][3]=name[c][2]
    name[c][2]=score
else:
    file.write(info)

file.close()


print("You scored",score,"out of 10.")
```

Here's what I'm seeing: [image]

Comment: can you post the full error?

Comment: Traceback ? what ? which recent call ?

Comment: that is the full error - i've edited my post with a screenshot. @bladexeon

Comment: Are you sure the edit went through? I don't see any screenshot, and there's only the original version on the post revisions page.

Comment: that's the whole thing @anmol_uppal! i've posted a screenshot on the original post.

Comment: Ok, I see it now, thanks :-) This looks like IDLE being weird as usual. Try running your script from the command line. You will probably get a more informative error message.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you open the command prompt by going to the start menu, choosing "run", entering "cmd" into the text box, and pressing OK. Then you navigate to the directory containing your script; `cd foldername` to move down into a folder, `cd ..` to move out. Then you execute the script with `python your_script_name.py`.

Comment: @gulliver To get to the command line on OS X: go to the /Applications/Utilities folder on your computer.  Double click 'Terminal', type 'python' and hit enter.

Comment: @gulliver "That isn't working" isn't a solvable problem, unfortunately. We need to know why or how it isn't working

Comment: @Kevin -  i managed it finally, hahaha! i got "Traceback (most recent call last): File "./student.py", line 108, in <module> name[count].append(data[1]) IndexError: list index out of range".

Answer (score 0):

The problem begins with the fact that you're opening a file for writing (by using the `'a'` mode) and then trying to read from it. If you change that to `'r+'` the problem may solve itself. Without an actual traceback there's no way to know for sure.

Comment: i've tried this, and it didn't work for me. i'm struggling to get an actual traceback - i'm a bit of a newbie ahaha!

Comment: @gulliver open your terminal and type `python3 path/to/your/python/file.py`

Comment: @gulliver you need to run it with `python3`, not just `python`. You've written code in Python3 (where the result of the `input` call is a string), and generally a system `python` is Python2 (where the result of the `input` call is a reference to a Python object)

Comment: i managed it finally, hahaha! sorry about that. i got
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./student.py", line 108, in <module>
    name[count].append(data[1])
IndexError: list index out of range".

Comment: @gulliver whatever line you were on doesn't contain commas (it might be blank?)

Comment: the text file i'm using contains the following:
lily,wilks,2,1,12
jeremy,james,10,9,8
celery,cabbage,2,6,4
peanut,jenkins,1,3,1
geoff,rey,3,2,3

so it should definitely be able to provide [1]s for all of those, shouldn't it?

Comment: @gulliver unless the last line in your file is blank? Or there are any blank lines in the middle? Or any of a bunch of things that could have happened? You need to debug this on your own